# Ionic 2/3 custom component with ionic cli

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-cli

If one uses the ionic cli to generate a component

```
ionic g component foobar
```

And then tries to use that selector

```
<foobar></foobar>
```

There is an error

> Error: Template parse errors: 'foobar' is not a known element:

This is without any changes at all made to the code.

In the generated `.ts` file there is a suggested link for more details

```
/**
 * Generated class for the FoobarComponent component.
 *
 * See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ComponentMetadata-class.html
 * for more info on Angular Components.
 */
```

But this just navigates to a 404 page.

Anyone know if this is a known issue and if there is a workaround?

Comment: If I understand you correct you are using latest version of Ionic 3 which have some issues with providing new feature of lazy loading. Please read about it [here](http://blog.ionic.io/ionic-and-lazy-loading-pt-1/) They will update ionic-cli soon.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and it's taken me a while to figure it out. I used the CLI tool to generate the custom component, which seems to have a slight issue. In my `custom-component.module.ts` the generator had added

```
...
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
...
imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(CustomComponent),
  ],
...
```

Changing these lines to

```
...
import { IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
...
imports: [
    IonicModule,
  ],
...
```

Fixes the main issue. To use `<custom-component>` in a page's HTML you then have to import the `custom-component.module` into the page module where you want to use it. For example if you wanted to use your component on the home page edit `home-page.module.ts`

```
...
import { CustomComponentModule } from "../../components/custom-component/custom-component.module";
...
imports: [
    CustomComponentModule,
    IonicPageModule.forChild(JobsPage),
  ],
...
```

And that seems to work for me!